# Starting a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated

Tags: android

I programming an app on Android Studio 2.3, which uses SQLite Databases and uploads data via an HTTP connection. Since I installed Android O on my Nexus 6P I have a problem.

**What's my problem**

I get the following information message every second when my app is running.

```
05-19 20:20:43.560 20029-20036/net.example.app I/chatty: uid=10378(u0_a378) JDWP identical 8 lines
05-19 20:20:44.059 20029-20036/net.example.app I/zygote64: Starting a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
```

So this continues in an endless log. I really don't know what it can be. I also noticed that the device will get hot.

Now my question, does anyone has the same problem or is there a solution?

Please feel free to ask for some code.

Comment: I too am seeing this

Comment: Happens to me with the latest O on my N5x. I only see that in the debug mode though.
Phone freezes when database and network is accessed.

Comment: Seeing same endless log :( No answer? Strange!!!

Answer (score 5):

It's harmless. It's an extra log message that was added to the GC in Android O as part of the solution to a potential deadlock. [Here's the commit in Android ART GC that causes it](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/e8649c7f1f1c21fdee1a40068c03d1e294e397ca%5E%21/).

The reason you're seeing it is because the "Memory" monitor tab in Android Studio polls the count of objects allocated periodically (quite frequently) in order to display the memory graph.

Workaround: disable the Android Studio memory monitor.